# ASP.NET MVC User.Identity.Name is Blank

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am attempting to build an ASP.NET MVC website which allows certain domain users to login and access the various functions it offers. I'm building this using Azure AD which Azure has a really nice way of letting you download a pre-built application which comes withe a Windows login page and authenticates the user already.

Here is the login page. It is even pre-populated with my domain.

```
Username@mydomain.com
```

[image]

After a successful login however the User.Identity.Name property is null.

[image]

I did some searching online and found a ton of posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28001027/6827790) that recommended turning Anonymous Authentication off and Windows Authentication on in the project properties. I gave that a shot but it automatically signs me in, completely bypassing the login page, and the User.Identity.Name is the name of the PC I'm developing this on. Is there a way to have Windows Authentication enabled and still have the login page working?

**EDIT 1:**
I forgot to mention, the User.Identity.Name property is null after the user has been authenticated for login.

Comment: have you tried to run the app in anonymous window? There may be authentication cookies in the browser.

Comment: I've tried clearing the browser history. I'm developing in Visual Studio 2017 Pro so it's running an IIS Express browser when I debug it.